# Python Thread.start() throws weird exception relating to datetime.datetime

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7

I'm using threading.Timer on python 2.74. This is the relevant piece of code:

```
__lock = threading.Lock()
def RegeneratePopulationData():
    __lock.acquire()
    print 'I feel regenerated!'
    __lock.release()

def __setRegenerationTimer(firstTime = False):
    global __regenerationTimer
    now = _getNow().date()
    nextRun = datetime(now.year, now.month, now.day + 1, 2, 0)
    __regenerationTimer = threading.Timer((nextRun - _getNow()).total_seconds(), __setRegenerationTimer)
    print 'Regeneration timer set to run in %s' % (nextRun - _getNow())
    print __regenerationTimer.interval
    __regenerationTimer.start()
    if not firstTime:
        RegeneratePopulationData()

def _getNow():
        return datetime.now() + timedelta(hours = TIME_DIF)
```

This cause a TypeError exception to be thrown from threading.py. I've searched the net for hours, and couldn't find a solution.

After changing the code at threading.py (for debugging purposes), around line 349, to:

```
            # than 20 times per second (or the timeout time remaining).
            print _time()
            print timeout
            endtime = _time() + timeout
            delay = 0.0005 # 500 us -> initial delay of 1 ms
```

This is the exception I'm getting:

```
Regeneration timer set to run in 2:52:12.337000
10332.337
1377634067.66
10332.337
1377634067.66
2013-08-27 21:07:47.663000
Exception in thread Thread-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 812, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 1082, in run
    self.finished.wait(self.interval)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 622, in wait
    self.__cond.wait(timeout)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 350, in wait
    endtime = _time() + timeout
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'datetime.datetime'
```

I can't figure out why the interval is suddenly turning into datetime!

Can anyone please help?

Comment: What's up with the double underscores? You usually only see those in class definitions, but there's no `self` in this code.

Comment: I was going to suggest that you add `id(self)` to your traces in threading.py to see if there is another object doing wait in your program. But you accepted @Marin's answer... does that mean the problem is fixed?

Comment: @tdelaney That's what I did eventually, and that was the problem. Since I wrongfully presented the problem as one stemming from threading.py, I accepted this answer so no one else would waste their time on this question... His final advice was to debug, and that was how I picked it up eventually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code doesn't show where `timeout` is coming from. It's not "suddenly becoming" anything. Whatever your code, at some point previously, a `datetime.datetime` was assigned to `timeout`. Either eliminate that condition, or handle it appropriately (perhaps by catching the exception).

Update: You're modifying standard library code, which is an awful idea. Directly or indirectly, you're passing in a `datetime.datetime`. Use `pdb` to figure out where. Run your code in the python console. When you trigger the exception do `import pdb; pdb.pm()`, and you'll drop into the debugger at the site of the exception. You can explore from there.

Comment: My code doesn't touch the timeout variable. I've posted the entire relevant code. Everything else is done internally at threading.py which is, afaik, infrastructure python code.

Comment: @TalKremerman That's a terrible idea. Use the builtin python debugger to inspect values, and discover where `timeout` is assigned.

Comment: Your question says otherwise. Which is it?

Comment: OK, I apologize for being unclear. The exception happens regardless of me doing that small change to the library code. The change to the library code was done only to emphasize what's going on. I thought that posting with that information (and not with "I debugged and...") would make it clearer. I can't seem to find where timeout is being changed, otherwise I would not have posted the question.
Also, I am most definitely NOT passing a datetime there. That's also clear from the code and the output.

Comment: @TalKremerman My answer addresses your problem: Use a debugger to find out where you are introducing this error.

Comment: Most of the time, when you're vehemently sure something couldn't be the source of the problem, it's the source of the problem. Are you *sure* you're not passing a datetime? Are you *sure* this is the "relevant part"? Are you *sure* you didn't mess up your Python install by editing `threading.py`?